# Twilio programmable video for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, twilio

Is Twilio programmable video be accessible to Xamarin, either through client library or wrapper of each mobile SDK?

Answer (score 5):

We are currently working on Xamarin bindings for [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video).

I will update this question with code samples as they become available.

Comment: Hi @Megan Speir .. do you have any good news about this ? we really need it so bad

Comment: @Megan Speir Any updates? Would be a awesome to implement this in Xamarin

Comment: Nothing official yet, however I can suggest you check out this project and reach out to the creator with any questions: https://github.com/jonedavis/TwilioXamarinRoomsSampleIOS

Comment: @MeganSpeir any further word on when Xamarin bindings for Twilio Video will be released? Would be especially great to have version 2.x compatible support.

Comment: @MeganSpeir Has this gotten any momentum?

Comment: any good news? event have this bindings. but is very hard for Xamarin beginner to start code a jump start project under twilio video conference

Answer (score 4):

As I know Twilio stopped working on Xamarin bindings. So nothing official yet. I suggest you to check out unofficial Xamarin bindings, there are some of them on github, so there is no need to write your own.

We're using Twilio SDKs with Xamarin for apps in Google Play and App Store, so we're trying to support and update bindings regularly and publishing them as nuget packages.

https://github.com/dkornev/TwilioXamarinBindings

Comment: Has anyone tried to update the Twilio.Video Library to 2.* version?

Comment: I'm still supporting my repository and have plans to update Twilio.Video to 2.*, but  only in 1 - 2 months, also have Twilio.Voice for Android in the queue before that. Anyway I think that it's not a big deal and if you want to help, feel free to contribute

Comment: Hey @DenisKornev - any plans to bring this back or provide an archived version if the project is not something being worked on?

Comment: The link is broken.  The repo been moved to here https://github.com/xamarin-bindings-for-twilio

Answer (score 0):

I have this binding working with twilio v6.2.0
I've tested it and it is working in production (at least on Android).

https://github.com/guillermo-gerard/Twilio.Video.Android.Xamarin.Binding

Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the github community where we get frequent updates on newer versions of Twilio.Voice and Twilio.Video for Xamarin (Android and iOS).  Thanks for the community members!

https://github.com/xamarin-bindings-for-twilio